# What is Wicket's sequence of events?

Tags: wicket

I am new to Wicket. I have gone through some examples, but I am still not sure what Wicket's order of execution is.

Can someone tell me, for this example

http://wicketstuff.org/wicket14/echo/

what methods are called, when and in what order? If I want to clear the fields after submit, what needs to be added?

For example, in Struts 2, the system would call `prepare()`, setter methods, `validate()` and `execute()`, in that order. In the same way, what is the order for Wicket?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never done any struts myself, but from what i read it is very different from Wicket.

I can 't tell you the names of the functions being called, but the order of execution is as follows:

1. values from the input fields are converted. If this fails, an error is flagged at that component and processing stops here
2. Converted values are validated against any registered Validators (.setRequired(true), or min-max,..)
3. values are pushed into your Model
4. onSubmit() of the submitting component (SubmitButton) is called.
5. onSubMit() of the Form is called

In case of an conversion or Validation error, the onError() of the SubmitComponent and Form are called.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: thanks for the response. I sort of needed the methods, because, that way I will know if I want a desired a result, I would know which method to manipulate. The example mentioned above has a getter and setter for a property, has a constructor and the button itself has an onsubmit event. between these three what the order of events. Thanks for your help

Comment: @user373201 just as i wrote. the setters for the properties are called when the Model is updated. The onSubmit() i did mention and the constructor does, of course, construct the page. it is not called in subsequent render phases. I have done a bit of wicked programming, but the hardly ever needed more detail. If you do, i suggest you debug through it.

Comment: Place a breakpoint and go over the code to see the order of execution.

Comment: @user373201 If you come from a Struts background, beware that Wicket represents a completely different way of thinking. In particular, don't put anything in `onSubmit()` that can be done using `Model` updates.

Answer (score 0):

Place a breakpoint and go over the code to see the order of execution.  It is pretty much different than struts. you set your method names yourself in your page so there is no predefined method like struts execute. You should read some wiki to get the idea.

https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/wicket-reference.html